# Save and restore a WebView state in which a movie is embedded (vimeo)

Tags: android

I write an Android app whose role in the world is to open an existing site where video clips are embedded and allow viewing it through the application.

I have 2 problems:

1. When the screen is rotated (the screen mode changes) the movie returns to the beginning as if it did not work (even though I restore the movie mode).
2. It is not possible to enlarge and reduce the viewing window to full screen, although through the code I implemented the `onShowCustomView` and `onHideCustomView` functions.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView My_wv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        My_wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings my_ws = My_wv.getSettings();
        my_ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        My_wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // Do I need to keep WebViewClient variable as well (instead of doing new WebViewClient() each time) ? If so how? Bundle outState has already taken by WebView

        //The functions is empty , implemented only to allow the Android to display a magnification and a screen reduction 
        My_wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {    
            public void onShowCustomView (View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {

            }

            public void onHideCustomView () {

            }
        });

        if(null == savedInstanceState) {
            My_wv.loadUrl("http://www.my-site.com");
        }else
        {
            My_wv.restoreState(savedInstanceState); //I added it because it seems that Androidoid is ignoring onRestoreInstanceState function
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(My_wv.canGoBack()) {
            My_wv.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
    {
        My_wv.saveState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        My_wv.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my-site.www.myapp">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>  // Added for Internet permissions

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  // Added to prevent my app from being refreshed every time the screen rotates
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.my-site.www.myapp.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i Found this places:

`https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html`
`https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView/tree/6e5f9430e35d6de87ca8182912871ab62057d2f7`

that help me realized that i better implementing my own WebView....

Hope these links will help people with similar problems in the future.